# sort javascript array by each object attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I Have an array named 'treeArray':

```
Array[78]
 0
 *function:Object
 *menu :
       id:1
       id_parent:1
       name:"Settings"
 1
 *function:Object
 *menu:
       id:1
       id_parent:1
       name:"Settings"      

 2
 *function:Object
 *menu:
       id:1
       id_parent:2
       name:"game"
```

I would like to get two arrays : 
The first one would contain Objects which follows :

```
 menu.id=menu.id_parent
```

and the second one  where

```
menu.id!=menu.id_parent
```

How can i achieve this with lodash ? 
Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`_.partition`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#partition) like

```
_.partition(treeArray, function(item) {
    return item.menu.id === item.menu.id_parent;
})
```

it returns `[[...truthly items...], [...falsy items...]]`